# Binding Nested Collections

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I am not understanding why the following xaml not properly grouping items.  The following code creates a group for each item in the _Portfolios property of the DataContext.  However, all the Program items are being populated in the first Program item and none in the second.

**Update 6/16/2013:**
_Portfolios is a method on the pages ViewModel that returns IObservableCollection<Portfolio>.
Each Portfolio has a property called Programs that returns IObservableCollection<Program> which also has a Name property.  In my mind, this xaml should produce two boxes: one for portfolio Aircraft which contains the planes and one for Navy which contains the boats.  Sadly it does not :(

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding _Portfolios}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>

                    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Programs}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>    

                </Grid>


            </Border>

        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>

</GridView>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you define _Portfolios? How did you define Programs. How do you fill the collections in code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you sent me the project files I found out that in your PortfolioRepository.cs class you are only adding to first Portfolio entity

```
p1.Programs.Add(new entity.Program() { Id = 1, Name = "Battleship" });
p1.Programs.Add(new entity.Program() { Id = 2, Name = "Aircraft Carrier" });
```

changing that to the following worked

```
p2.Programs.Add(new entity.Program() { Id = 1, Name = "Battleship" });
p2.Programs.Add(new entity.Program() { Id = 2, Name = "Aircraft Carrier" });
```

After the above change the output looks like this

[image]